# Integrating elFinder, TinyMCE to Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, tinymce-4, elfinder

I am using this [package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder) and somehow I am getting an error in the console.  This is what js looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/admin/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#editor1',
            plugins: "image imagetools",
            file_browser_callback : "elFinderBrowser"
          });

        function elFinderBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
          tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: '<?= route('elfinder.tinymce4') ?>',// use an absolute path!
            title: 'elFinder 2.0',
            width: 900,
            height: 450,
            resizable: 'yes'
          }, {
            setUrl: function (url) {
              win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
            }
          });
          return false;
        }
    </script>
```

This gives an error: `Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong in this line:

```
file_browser_callback : "elFinderBrowser"
```

elFinderBrowser it's not string but function callback so it should be without " ", like this:

```
file_browser_callback : elFinderBrowser
```